# Protect local logic in phonegap apps

Tags: javascript, android, security, cordova

I want to build a small game with phonegap/cordova and javascript. A player can collect scores by some actions. The collection process and lose/win detection is on client side (say, on an Android phone). I want to allow players to rank globally. So the result will be posted to the server.

As the JS source code is not compiled, it is easily to modify and some player can always make himself win with a super high score.

How can I avoid this if I still want to use phonegap? Is it possible to use js encryption thing like http://www.vincentcheung.ca/jsencryption/instructions.html on PhoneGap apps (if so, how)?